# Twitter4J.Status conflicts with android.os.AsyncTask.Status?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, twitter4j

I have the following code for fetching tweets via Twitter4J:

```
List<Status> statuses;
Paging paging = new Paging(1, LIMIT);
statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(USER, paging);
```

This works fine by itself, but if I move this code into an AsyncTask and import android.os.AsyncTask, the Status class changes from twitter4j.Status to android.os.AsyncTask.Status automatically, which breaks a bunch of stuff.

Any idea why this happens, and what I can do to fix it? I realize Twitter4J is thread safe, I'm just curious and a little confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define `Status` by its full package and class name: `List<twitter4j.Status> statuses;`